# Orthogonal idempotents with sum equal to 1 in $k[G]$ span sub-Hopf algebra

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, finite-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $B$ be a set of orthogonal non-zero idempotents with $|B| \leq |G|$, s.t. $\sum_{b \in B}b =1_{kG}$. Is it known if $B$ spans a sub-Hopf algebra $kH \subseteq kG$?

Answer (score 2):

In general no. Take for example $G=C_3, e = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}g$ and $B=\{1-e,e\}$. Then $B$ spans a sub algebra, but not a sub-Hopf algebra. This was a particular example, but for most finite groups $G$ and most sets of idempotents you will not get the group algebra of a subgroup.
In fact, any sub-Hopf algebra which contains $e$ must coincide with $kG$.

Comment: Thx, Udi! (says Tobi from the office next door ;)) So, maybe I am stupid but  this $B$ is not orthogonal (in the sense that $b_ib_j=\delta_{ij}b_j$), right?

Comment: Doch. I am not allowed to write less than 15 characters, so here they are. Otherwise, just Doch.

Comment: this is getting embarassing for me but $(1-e)\cdot e=1-e \neq 0$?

Comment: $(1-e)e = e-e^2=0$.

Comment: sorry, I screwed up in so many ways... the thing is that I forgot to exclude zero-idempotents, sorry for the waste of time!